# Finding the destination of an ad

Tags: javascript, php, http, adsense

Is there a way to find the destination URL of an ad served by AdSense on my site? I'm trying to avoid advertising for particular companies, so if their ads show up, I'm happy to take down the whole element. Alternatively though, some advertisers use a very contrasting colour to my website, like bright red. If I can find the destination URL, I can try changing the colour of the surrounding region on my page to one that matches.

Some ads are even in Flash, so is there a way to find the destination URL without clicking the ad?

Comment: Just filter it in your admin area on adsense

Comment: I'm fairly sure you would be breaking Google's T&C by fiddling with their ads, and would find yourself kicked out  very quickly. Doesn't Adsense provide a straightforward way to deal with this? I thought I remembered it did.

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively though, some advertisers use a very contrasting colour to my website, like bright red. If I can find the destination URL, I can try changing the colour of the surrounding region to one that matches.

Comment: You'll get kicked out for doing that. You can't change the ad in any way

Comment: @Pekka Right. But I'm not trying to manipulate the ad itself though. Does that still violate the T&C? I'm trying to change the region within my site.

Comment: @kate.r taking the ad down will get you kicked. From their  [T&C:](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms) `[you will not] (ii) edit, modify, filter, truncate or change the order of the information contained in any Ad,..., or remove, obscure or minimize any Ad ... in any way without authorization from Google; ` your second bullet point might be less problematic but will probably be much tougher to impement technically.

Comment: I think you will be banned by Google if you try to do something like that.